# Restart the whole script in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to restart script in python. This is the way I tried but it just gets stuck after some time. And when i use the `os.excel` and `os.excev` it doesn't work it just returns a error

```
os.system("start cmd /c python" + __file__)
```

So, What I need to do is make this function restart the script

```
def main():
  os.system("start cmd /c python" + __file__)
```

If anybody knows the answer, please help

Comment: Put the things you are trying to do in a function, and control when that function is called or not called in a loop

Comment: I am a beginner in python so can u explain what you just told now

Comment: BTW the `os` functions you mentioned are [`os.execl`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.execl) and `os.execv`, among others.

Comment: You just defined a function in your example. Do the same with whatever you want to re-run (it could be the whole script). And then put it inside a loop: a `for` loop if you want to re-run it a number of times, a `while` if you want to re-run it based on some state. You can also just put everything inside the loop without defining a function, that's just for readability. Using these loops is a lot more basic than everything else you're trying to do, there's a lot of quick tutorials all over the internet.

Comment: I think you should figure out why it hangs and either fix that issue or if not create a flag to determine if it is hanging and call the function over again using a while true loop. But again determining what is causing it to hang may be the more important step.

Comment: @Ignatius Reilly thanks man the loop helped me I just added a while true: loop

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop like this

```
while True:
  #Your code here

continue
```

The continue will start the code from `while True:`